# is it possible to have gradient opacity without color?

Tags: jquery, html, css

what im trying to achieve here is to have opacity like gradient, so that the element is gradually invisible as i scroll through.

is it possible in CSS?

I have tried this :

```
-webkit-mask-position: 0 0;
-webkit-mask-size: 200px 200px;
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, 
   color-stop(0.00,  rgba(0,0,0,1)),
   color-stop(0.45,  rgba(0,0,0,1)),
  color-stop(0.50,  rgba(0,0,0,0)),
  color-stop(0.55,  rgba(0,0,0,0)),
   color-stop(1.00,  rgba(0,0,0,0)));
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

is there anyway i can achieve this?

P.S. 
QUESTION REPHRASE

i have a question : is it possible to make contents become invisible or at least have opacity value as i scroll through, so that they become gradually invisible?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot that what you need actually?

Comment: the basic idea is something like this : http://media.wiley.com/Lux/79/333779.image1.jpg but the content has to have 'opacity' not white value.

Comment: Can you use a colored gradient that has the background color? Setting "invisible" via gradient isn't possible afaik.

Comment: @Arerrac impossible? okay.

Comment: The image you've shown would be working with a white gradient :)

Comment: @Arerrac you are missing the point.

Comment: Do you want something like this? : https://jsfiddle.net/rzp1ffau/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xbkg9vgq/

Comment: @KhanhTO very clever. haha but no. i meant the images to be gradually transparent from top to bottom, not appear gradually.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you want, but we can use a similar code using css keyframes.

Comment: @KhanhTO yeah. it just stroke me that i can utilize the idea of yours to actually make contents invisible when they exceed certain scroll....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic example of your screenshot.

```css
.gradient{
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.gradient::after{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&0.65+0,0+100 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.65) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0.65) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0.65) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
  <h5>Coming soon!</h5>
  <h4>Coming soon!</h4>
  <h3>Coming soon!</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: to tell you the truth this isn't the right answer,but i already got the answer from irc chat channel, and you came in the closeset. and i need +2 points lol

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question really, I mean what does it mean *as I scroll*?
Anyway, here's a gradient in svg: https://jsfiddle.net/n2u8q3wv/1/

```
<svg width="600" height="311">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="fadeGrad" y2="1" x2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
      <stop offset=".7" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="masking" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect width="1" height="1" fill="url(#fadeGrad)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://memesvault.com/wp-content/uploads/Doge-Meme-08.jpg" width="600" height="311" mask="url(#masking)"></image>
</svg>
```